# Transfer question from electrical engineering

Tags: feature-request, scope

I don't have rep on that site so could someone consider moving https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79447/can-a-circuit-be-powered-from-earth-with-a-return-ground-on-mars to physics SE? It seems like a really good question.

Comment: WHY downvote? Please leave a comment explaining your downvote.

Comment: This can't be moved by users here, so you're asking in the wrong place. It can be moved by moderators on EE if you flag it, but they're unlikely to do so unless it's off-topic there. There isn't a migration path set up from EE to Physics so the only way to migrate it is by EE mods. (btw I'm not the one who downvoted.)

Comment: But I don't have rep even to flag there.

Comment: I guess you could try to contact their moderators in their chatroom also, or just go get 15 rep to flag. In any case, I'm not sure if they'd agree that it's off-topic there. In cases where two sites have overlapping scope, moderators generally don't migrate things that are on-topic on both sites.

Comment: @LoganM maybe you could make an answer out of these comments